# Laravel can't update database?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

This is a weird error. I can add a new record to the database fine with a new UserEdit method, but if I try to update a record. Nothing. It doesn't even file a blank value, or issue an error.

What am I missing? To try to eliminate issues, I tried running the core update method in the documentation like so:

```
protected function create()
    {
        $save = UserEdit::find(715);
        $save->First_Name = 'Jeffrey';
        $save->Last_Name = 'Way';
        $save->save();
        $id = UserEdit::find(715)->toArray();
        return view('NewUser', compact('id'));
        //return $array;
    }
```

This problem is the same as my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038692/laravel-form-not-submitting-data-to-database), but I didn't think it appropriate to double up the questions and this is technically a different problem. My blade just prints an array of the user data at the moment so I know if it's working or not:

@extends('layout')

```
@section('content')
    <h1> Add Your Information {{ $id['name'] }}</h1>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    @foreach ($id as $key=>$value)
        {{ $value }}<br>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@stop
```

The Routes:

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::get('NewUser', 'UserEntryController@create');
Route::post('NewUser', 'UserEntryController@UserForm');
Route::post('NewUser', 'UserEntryController@UserForm')->name('submit');
```

I'm assuming I'm missing some crucial minor detail, but for the life of me, can't find what. Anybody got an idea where to look?

Comment: At least do some basic debugging. It's clear from above that the method you want to run is create where as in routing, you are pointing it to UserForm.

Comment: The Userform code won't trigger until a post request is made. That's why the get request is pointing to create as I want to debug without shuffling my pages around. I know when the Userform code gets triggered as it has a redirect to another page when it completes. Which isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new UserEdit;

        //$user->name = $request->name;
        $user->First_Name = "foo";
        $user->Last_Name = "bar";

        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }
```

Try this function, maybe you had a mistake in your code.

Comment: As noted before. $user = new UserEdit; will work. We can write to the database fine.

Comment: Have you tried to put there `edit code` in to `try - catch`.
I think it's around some reasons:
1. `UserEdit` with id `715` is not exists.
2. You has typo in `UserEdit` attributes.
3. You don't need to use `->toArray();`, the function compact had already do convert $id to an array.

Comment: Compact seems to send the array as an object, which cannot be parsed with array logic. It just returns numerical ids. So the ->toArray(); makes sure that the array can actually be read in the proper format on the other end, including allowing me to designate values I don't want publically visible. 
Catch won't trigger if there's no error, UserEdit 715 exists in the database and there's no typos as UserEdit is using values generated directly from the database [link](https://laravel-news.com/2016/09/improved-model-generation-with-laracademy-generators/). Those are the first things I check